# Trouble passing object through other methods

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate brightness using the formula 
 = √0.2412 + 0.6912 + 0.0682

brightness is easy enough to understand as it is a double which i can set privately then make a standard get and set method for, for the colors im using the java.awt.color library, and im confused as how to use only one get and set method for color in order to set the three variables of color in this equation.

i have something like this right now

```
public Color setColor(Color color){
    return Color;

}

public double brightness(){
    this.brightness = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(0.241 * getColor(RED), 2) + Math.pow(0.691*getColor(GREEN),2) + Math.pow(0.068*getColor(BLUE),2)))

}
```

}

just as a general idea

Comment: your method isn't returning anything but it has a return type of `double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> im confused as how to use only one get and set method for color in
>   order to set the three variables of color in this equation.

Well, can't you get and set a `Color` object?  A `Color` object contains all three components, and it has methods like `.getBlue()` that you can use to get at those components.  To create a `Color`, you can use the constructor that takes the red, green, and blue values as parameters.

You currently have this confused code:

```
public Color setColor(Color color){
    return Color;
}
```

That's wrong and likely won't even compile.  If you're setting the color, it should look more like this:

```
public void setColor(Color color){
    this.color = color;
}
```